# how to set value of an arg in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have an assignment question like so:

```
Write a program to find the last element of a list. e.g.
?- last(X, [how, are, you]).
X = you
Yes
```

I'm currently finding the last element like this:

```
last([Y]) :-
    write('Last element ==> '),write(Y).
last([Y|Tail]):-
    last(Tail).
```

And it works.  My question is, how do I change it to accept and set the addition X parameter and set it correctly?

I tried this, but it's not working ...

```
last(X, [Y]) :-
    X is Y.

last(X, [Y|Tail]):-
    last(X, Tail).
```

Comment: Please consider explaining in the question **what** and **how** "it's not working ..."

Comment: idiomatically: `last(X, [X]) :- !.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most obvious problem: `(is)/2` works with numbers only. ([link](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28is%29/2))

> -Number is +Expr
>       True when Number is the value to which Expr evaluates

You want to use the unification operator `(=)/2` ([link](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28=%29/2)):

```
last(X, [Y]) :-
    X = Y,
    !.

last(X, [_|Tail]):-
    last(X, Tail).
```

Let's try:

```
?- last(X, [1, 2, 3]).
X = 3.

?- last(X, [a, b, c]).
X = c.
```

Comment: Thanks.  Just FYI, looks like it doesn't need the cut (!), and also `last(X,[X]).` works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using the unification operator is not the preferred way to unify in a case like this.  You can use unification in a much more powerful way.  See the following code:

```
last(Y, [Y]).  %this uses pattern matching to Unify the last part of a list with the "place holder"
               %writing this way is far more concise.
               %the underscore represents the "anonymous" element, but basically means "Don't care"

last(X, [_|Tail]):-
last(X, Tail).
```